# JSON Decode Function From File Versus Web

Tags: ios, json, swift

SwiftUI is supposed to simplify things- I am bit frustrated as I have been working on the URLSession+JSONDecoder for weeks, I really need some help!

I have a function to load JSON data from a file in Swift and it works as expected. I copy/pasted the function and updated it to get the data via an API, however I receive a compile time error: "Unexpected non-void return value in void function". Is my approach wrong to use a function for JSON over the web?

JSON response:

```
{
"T":"CSU",
"v":468303,
"vw":1.2838,
"o":1.31,
"c":1.24,
"h":1.38,
"l":1.2001,
"t":1607374800000,
"n":994
}

struct Root2: Codable {
    var T: String
    var v: Double
    var vw: Double
    var o: String
    var c: String
    var h: Double
    var l: Double
    var t: Double
}
```

This file-based function works as expected:

```
let symbolData: [Root2] = load("symbolData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

For the web version, I receive compile time error: "Unexpected non-void return value in void function".
Line:  return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)

```
func loadURL<T: Decodable>() -> T {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: """)
    else {
        fatalError("Invalid URL in main bundle.")
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        do {
            if let data = data {
                let stringData = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                print("1 Fetched: \(url)")
                print("2 Response: \(stringData)")
                
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            }
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't parse as :\n\(error)")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Working version after Leo's help!

```
class Manager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var symbols: [Symbol] = []
   
    func loadURL<T: Decodable>(using decoder: JSONDecoder = .msSince1970, completion: @escaping ((T?, Error?) -> Void)) {
        let url = URL(string: """)!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("ops")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            print("1 Fetched: \(url)")
            print("2 Response:", String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
            _ = Data("""
            [
              {
                "open": {
                  "price": 124.02,
                  "time": 1657105851499
                },
                "close": {
                  "price": 124.96,
                  "time": 1618647822184
                },
                "high": 124.64,
                "low": 124.65,
                "volume": 75665274,
                "symbol": "AAPL"
              }
            ]
            """.utf8)
            do {
                completion(try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data), nil)
                //completion(try decoder.decode(T.self, from: tempDataForTesting), nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

extension JSONDecoder {
    static let msSince1970: JSONDecoder = {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
        return decoder
    }()
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused: this question is identical to the last question you posted, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281062/load-json-data-jsondecode-error-in-swift), aside from the plea to not close as duplicate (which I removed, as that doesn't belong in a title or description of a question). If you feel your originally-closed question is not a duplicate of the one it was marked duplicate as, then you should include that in your question and explain why it's not a duplicate, so that it won't be closed again. But posting an identical question is not really helpful.

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask) for URLSession.dataTask, the closure returns Void, that is nothing so you can’t return anything from it. Read the duplicate link in your previous question

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your message. Maybe I don't understand stackoverflow's approach as I am relatively new. However, I believe posting a question about the difference between decoding JSON using a file versus a web-based version of the swift JSONDecoder is an interesting question to the community. Would you not agree?

Comment: The difference is that `URLSession` works **asynchronously** unlike `Data(contentsOf`. This question has been asked many many times.

Comment: Based on the feedback, I added a second version of the function above in the question. I now assign the results of the .decode and returning to the variable foo (also removed generics as it was complicating the function unnecessarily). Now an error pops up that the variable is assigned before being initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't wait for an asynchronous task to finish and return the result. What you need is a completion handler. You would need also to explicitly set the resulting type if you don't pass the resulting type to your decode method and you need to call resume to start your url session data task:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var manager = Manager()
    @State var string: String = "Hello, world!"
    var body: some View {
        Text(manager.symbol)
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            manager.load(symbol: manager.symbol) { (symbols: [Symbol]?, error: Error?) in
                guard let symbols = symbols else {
                    print("error:", error ?? "")
                    string = "JSON could not be parsed"
                    return
                }
                for symbol in symbols {
                    print(symbol.open.price)
                    print(symbol.open.time)
                    print(symbol.close.price)
                    print(symbol.close.time)
                    print(symbol.high)
                    print(symbol.low)
                    print(symbol.volume)
                    print(symbol.symbol)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        manager.symbols = symbols
                    }
                }
                string = "JSON was successufly parsed"
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

```
class Manager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var symbols: [Symbol] = []
    @Published var symbol: String = "IBM"
    func load<T: Decodable>(symbol: String, using decoder: JSONDecoder = .msSince1970, completion: @escaping ((T?, Error?) -> Void)) {
        guard let url = URLComponents(symbol: symbol).url else {
            completion(nil, URL.Error.invalidURL)
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("ops")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            print("1 Fetched: \(url)")
            print("2 Symbol: \(symbol)")
            print("3 Response:", String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
            do {
                completion(try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data), nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Symbol: Codable {
    let open, close: Price
    let high, low: Double
    let volume: Int
    let symbol: String
}
```

---

```
struct Price: Codable {
    let price: Double
    let time: Date
}
```

---

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    static let msSince1970: JSONDecoder = {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
        return decoder
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension URLComponents {
    init(scheme: String = "https",
         host: String = "sandbox.iexapis.com",
         path: String = "/stable/stock/market/ohlc",
         symbol: String,
         token: String = "YOUR_API_TOKEN") {
        self.init()
        self.scheme = scheme
        self.host = host
        self.path = path
        self.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "symbols", value: symbol),
                           URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: token)]
    }
}
```

---

```
extension URL {
    enum Error: String, Swift.Error {
        case invalidURL = "Invalid URL"
    }
}
```

---

This will print

> 1 Fetched: https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/ohlc?symbols=IBM&token=YOUR_API_TOKEN
> 2 Symbol: IBM
> 3 Response: [{"open":{"price":128.9,"time":1636600302693},"close":{"price":131.44,"time":1662259300134},"high":132.517,"low":130.074,"volume":3403359,"symbol":"IBM"}]
> 128.9
> 2021-11-11 03:11:42 +0000
> 131.44
> 2022-09-04 02:41:40 +0000
> 132.517
> 130.074
> 3403359
> IBM

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226069/discussion-on-answer-by-leo-dabus-json-decode-function-from-file-versus-web).